# Why does my program to calculate the average of numbers entered into a while loop not work as expected?

Tags: python, while-loop, average

I am new to coding. I would like to attend a course but there are assessments first in order to be chosen.

The question I am stuck on is:

> Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the user enters the negative number -1, the program should stop requesting the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered excluding the -1.

```
num = 0
inputs = []

while True:
  num = int(input("Please enter a number between -1 and 5: "))
  if num > -1:
    break
  else:
    inputs.append(int(num))

print (sum(inputs) / len(inputs))
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: It's the classic string to int problem.  Anyone know the canonical dupe?

Comment: @him which classic string to int problem?

Comment: Your test stops only when the number is greater than `-1`, presumably the test should be `if num == -1:`, not `if num > -1:`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: @kwinkunks it seems they already know how to do that.

Comment: I changed to == -1 and the loop just keeps asking for a number to be inputted rather than working out the average of each number that has been inputted so far

Answer (score 2):

so lets break this down together.

This is fine.

```
num = 0
inputs = []
```

You will want to modify this while true statement to be `while True` (if using python) like below

```
while True:
```

Next, it doesn't explicitly say integers, and technically there are different number types, but for simplicity sake we check to see if the number entered is an integer to avoid trying convert a letter to an integer. (This will cause a ValueError). We make a decision to ignore this type of bad input and continue.

```
  input_value = input("Please enter a number between -1 and 5: ")
  try:
    num = int(input_value)
  except ValueError:
    continue
```

The condition for stopping the loop is entering -1 (if I understood the question properly). So, first check to see if the number entered matches the condition to stop: `if num == -1: break`.

```
if num == -1:
    break
```

otherwise, you will want to check to be sure the number is in range before it is added to your inputs array, otherwise ignore it and wait for the next input.  The question asks for any number, but since you're prompting for specific input, we're making a decision here not to accept numbers out of bounds of what was prompted for.

```
elif num < -1 or num > 5:
    continue
```

Finally, if input is not -1, and the input is a number between 0-5 inclusive, add it to the array and await the next input.

```
  else:
    inputs.append(num)
```

Finally at the end of the return after -1 was received, it is possible the first number entered was -1, or all values entered were invalid. Both of these scenarios would result in division by 0, and an error being thrown. So you would want to set the minimum number that can be set as the divisor to 1 to ensure you don't crash trying to calculate your answer:

```
print(sum(inputs) / max(len(inputs), 1))
```

And now putting it all together:

```
num = 0
inputs = []

while True:
  input_value = input("Please enter a number between -1 and 5: ")
  try:
    num = int(input_value)
  except ValueError:
    continue
  if num == -1:
    break
  elif num < -1 or num > 5:
    continue
  else:
    inputs.append(num)

return sum(inputs) / max(len(inputs), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the code you are looking for just changing `if num > -1` to `if num == -1` to agree with the question you posted:

```
num = 0
inputs = []

while True:
  num = int(input("Please enter a number between -1 and 5: "))
  if num == -1:
    break
  else:
    inputs.append(num)

print(sum(inputs) / len(inputs))
```

and it works just fine having as a result:

```
Please enter a number between -1 and 5: 5
Please enter a number between -1 and 5: 4
Please enter a number between -1 and 5: 3
Please enter a number between -1 and 5: 2
Please enter a number between -1 and 5: 1
Please enter a number between -1 and 5: -1
3.0
```